# Android: Create Allocation from pixels array for renderscript

Tags: android, allocation, renderscript

I am trying to use the Android Renderscript for blurring an image. My input is an array of integers that containt the pixel's colors. Here's what I did and not worked. The application shut down without any error message on Galaxy S device

```
    bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());

    Allocation input = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.I32(rs), pixels.length);
    input.copy1DRangeFrom(0, pixels.length, pixels);

    Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setRadius(6f);
    script.setInput(input);
    script.forEach(output);

    output.copyTo(pixels);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look at the logcat output (make sure no filters are on in Android Studio / Eclipse), it will show you the crash.

The problem you're seeing is most likely because your input `Allocation` element type doesn't match the output.  They need to be the same.  Rather than call `Allocation.createSized()` and specify an element, just call [`Allocation.createFromBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#createFromBitmap(android.renderscript.RenderScript,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) and provide it with your input `Bitmap` object.  Then copy the input `Bitmap` into the `Allocation`.

Comment: There no error in the logcat, the application stop at "output.copyTo" line. In my case i don't have a Bitmap, the input is an array containing the pixels. Creating a bitmap from that array to use it for the Allocation is not a solution because it will slow down the process, and I need speed, it's a real time process.

Comment: There has to be something in the logcat, all crashes are logged, even if it is in native code or RS. You'd have to either create a bitmap or have it in a byte array so the allocation can be U8_4 compatible.